# Pluralische Quantoren

Tags: grammatical-number, synonym

"Mancher Hund" ist gleichbedeutend mit "manche/einige Hunde". "Jeder Hund" ist gleichbedeutend mit "alle Hunde". Warum gibt es keine singularischen Quantoren (wie "mancher" und "jeder"), die gleichbedeutend sind mit den pluralischen Quantoren "viele" oder "wenige"? Gibt es dafür eine Erklärung, oder ist das einfach so?

(Umgekehrt gibt es keinen pluralischen Quantor für den singularischen Quantor "kein".)

Comment: Rein logisch nicht sinnvoll und notwendig: Weil singular 'ein' es quantifiziert? Und ein Vielfaches von 'kein' immer noch 'kein' ist.

Comment: "eine Menge Hunde" ?

Comment: Es gebe keine singularischen Quantoren, die die Bedeutung "viele / wenige" ausdrücken, wurde gesagt. Da gibt es aber so manche Formulierung, die ein Gegenbeispiel *ist,* etwa auch: "Von dem Geld *lebt* eine Menge Leute".

Comment: @Alazon: Wenn der Vorschlag "so manche Formulierung" anstatt "viele Formulierungen" sein soll - den lasse ich mir durch den Kopf gehen. "So manche" klingt auf jeden Fall nach mehr als "manche". Interessant!

Comment: "Jeder Hund" ist nicht gleichbedeutend mit "alle Hunde". Beispielsweise kann jeder Berliner am Sonntag ins Olympiastadion kommen, aber nicht alle.

Comment: @userunknown: Sehr guter Punkt! Danke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dass es  keinen pluralischen Quantor für das Nichtvorhandensein von etwas  gibt, ist nicht richtig:

- singularisch

  > Diesen Raum darf kein Unbefugter betreten.
  > Unter den Teilnehmern war kein Mann.
- pluralisch

  > Diesen Raum dürfen keine Unbefugten betreten.
  > Unter den Teilnehmern waren keine Männer.
  > Walter und Sabine haben keine Kinder.

Wir haben also das:

| Bedeutung | singular | plural |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100% | jeder Hund | alle Hunde |
| eine große Teilmenge | ~ | viele/mehrere Hunde |
| eine beliebige Teilmenge | mancher Hund | manche/einige Hunde |
| eine kleine Teilmenge | ~ | wenige Hunde |
| 0% | kein Hund | keine Hunde |

Es gibt einen subtilen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen singularischen und pluralischen Quantoren: Die singularischen Quantoren legen den Fokus auf jedes einzelne Individuum der Gruppe. Wenn *jeder Schuss* ein Treffer ist, betont das die Abwesenheit von Fehlschüssen stärker als wenn *alle Schuss* ein Treffer sind. Und wenn im letzten Monat *kein Mitarbeiter* gekündigt hat, betont das stärker die Bindung der Mitarbeiter zum Unternehmen, als wenn man sagt, dass in letzten Monat *keine Mitarbeiter* gekündigt haben.
Und wenn man sagt, dass schon *mancher Gast* die Zeche geprellt hat, hat man einzelne individuelle Betrüger vor Augen, während man eher an ein Gruppe anonymer Personen denkt, wenn man hört, dass *manche Gäste* die Zeche geprellt haben.

Aber offenbar besteht dann, wenn man eine große Mehrheit oder eine kleine Minderheit meint, kein Bedarf, die Individualität der Mitglieder der Gruppe hervorzuheben.

Comment: Danke für die schöne und aufschlußreiche Antwort.

Comment: Bitte werfen Sie einen Blick auf meinen Nachtrag.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker: Es ist nicht erwünscht, bereits beantwortete Fragen inhaltlich so zu verändern, dass die bereits gegebenen Antworten nicht mehr zur veränderten Frage passen. Ich habe daher die Frage auf jenen Zustand zurückgesetzt, in dem sie war, als sie beantwortet wurde. Es ist jederzeit in Ordnung, Rechtschreibfehler oder die Formatierung zu verändern, aber inhaltliche Veränderungen sind unerwünscht, sobald es Antworten gibt. Wenn neue Fragen auftauchen, kann man hier neue Fragen stellen: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: Ok, ich dachte, die Durchstreichung stellte einen guten Kompromiss dar, und ein gekennzeichneter Nachtrag auch. Aber wenn das nicht erwünscht ist....

Comment: Scheinbar ist Zählbarkeit relevant für die Bedeutung. Wir können zB. trotzdem sagen _viel Teig_ und _wenig Teig_. _Viele/wenige Teige_ heißen aber wieder etwas anderes. Das liegt vermutlich deiner auf "Individualität" (ich würde eher von "Identifizierbarkeit" sprechen) beruhenden Analyse zugrunde. Auch wenn meiner Meinung nach die Unterschiede in deinen Beispielen in der Praxis sehr schwach sind.